# NetLogo map variable of patch in observer context

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to map a variable of patches in the same order as the list they were generated in (see code below). However, I get an "error while observer running SET test2" because it cannot be run in the observer context. I do not understand this as it seems like a straightforward procedure.

```
globals [test test2]
patches-own [wealth]
to setup
  ca
ask patches
  [set wealth random 100]
end
to go
  set test [self] of patches
  show test
  set test2 map [wealth] test
  show test2
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `set test2 map [wealth] test` to `set test2 map [x -> [wealth] of x] test`.  However, whenever you are working with lists of agents instead of agentsets, you should ask whether this is really necessary.

Comment: Seconded that you should be using agentsets instead unless you're completely sure you know what you're doing.